# How to perform pruning with a transfer learning model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, transfer-learning, pruning

Essentially, I want to perform pruning to my transfer learning model.

I used `efficientnetb0` for classifying microorganisms.

```
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

prune_low_magnitude = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude

# Compute end step to finish pruning after 2 epochs.
batch_size = 32
epochs = 25

end_step = np.ceil(len(training_set) / batch_size).astype(np.int32) * epochs

# Define model for pruning.
pruning_params = {
      'pruning_schedule': tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(
                                        initial_sparsity = 0.40,                                                                 
                                        final_sparsity = 0.90,                                                                   
                                        begin_step = 0,                                                                
                                        end_step = end_step
                                        )
                  }

model_for_pruning = prune_low_magnitude(
                         efficientnetb0_transfer_model, **pruning_params)

# `prune_low_magnitude` requires a recompile.
efficientnetb0_transfer_model_for_pruning.compile(optimizer=optim,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

efficientnetb0_transfer_model_for_pruning.summary()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Please initialize `Prune` with a supported layer. Layers should either be supported by the PruneRegistry (built-in keras layers) or should be a `PrunableLayer` instance, or should has a customer defined `get_prunable_weights` method. You passed: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing.image_preprocessing.Rescaling'>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting this [error](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/master/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/sparsity/keras/pruning_wrapper.py#L156-L161).

The pruning API is not flexible enough. It currently expects all layers in the model to be prunable (logic [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/master/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/sparsity/keras/pruning_wrapper.py#L147-L154)). Ideally it should be able to skip layers like image rescaling. Can you file a github issue and we'll work on a fix. Thanks!